# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar')

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop

Hello I am trying to use the them "Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar"

I updated my SDK and ADT, I have the latest lollipop phone. I am compiling it with android 5.1.

I changed manifest to

```
    android:minSdkVersion="22"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22"
```

Inside of my manifest I put:

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

However I get the error saying Error:
 No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar') .

How can i fix this so I can use this theme in my app please. ps I am using Eclipse.

Comment: If your activity extends `ActionBarActivity`, use `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" `.

Comment: Thanks!! I want to use Theme Material but also need to extend BaseActivity instead of Activity.. but It throws a error...?

Comment: `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` will default to `@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar` on API level >= 21. So, you don't have to worry about that. If you want to extend `BaseActivity`, make sure that `BaseActivity` extends `ActionBarActivity` and not `Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

To

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

Because it is an Android resource and not your project's resource.

Comment: I tried this now I get :   03-18 18:50:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2653): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.check.ing/com.check.ing.StartUpActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: Post you StartUpActivity.java please

Comment: You should extend `Activity` instead of `ActionBarActivity` to avoid the error.

Comment: Yes!! Also what if I want to extend BaseAcitvity??

Comment: I don't know `BaseActivity`, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As referenced in https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html 
you should try -

```
@android:style/Theme.Material.Light
```

Comment: Thanks!! I need to extend BaseActivity instead of Activity.. but It throws a error...?